# Is it possible to store videos in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to upload videos to `mysql` database(or another database) and then store them in this database but not on my own computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes. But you would almost certainly never do this (unless the files were very small), preferring instead to store the files in a file server, and only their paths and meta data in the database.

Comment: I guess file server it is my hard driver,right?

Comment: Well, it's someone's hard drive.